# Validation of not allowed username string in input form

Tags: php, mysql

I have a collection of string stored in database table separated by comma.

Table "not_allowed" content :

admin,administrator,register,email,password,username,database,computer,... etc. (as admin defind)

In user registration, I want that collection of string is "not allowed" as their username input.

How to make the validation in php in relation with database table content?

Manual scipt I have :

```
$notallowed = array('admin','administrator','register','email','password','username','database','computer',... etc);

if (in_array($username, $notallowed, true)) {
    $errors[] = 'The Selected username is not allowed! ';
}
```

Comment: What's not working with the script you have?

Comment: @MarkM, I don't want to type all the 'string' in the script, I need to get it from database table that the content can be edited by administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table in the DB called `not_allowed`. Use it to store all the not allowed strings. When a user signs in, query that table to get all the not allowed strings. Store the result in a variable and use it in the same way you use it now.

Depending on your program structure this can be done in different ways, but here's the basic idea using mysqli:

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM not_allowed");
$not_allowed = $query->fetch_array();

if (in_array($username, $not_allowed, true)) {
    $errors[] = 'The Selected username is not allowed! ';
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, I just don't realize that fetch_array() is a function too.. I am really stupid.

Comment: public function SelectNotAllowed() { 
$query = $this->db->prepare("Select `not_allowed` FROM website_setting` ");     
{ $query->execute();        
return $rows = $query->FETCH_ARRAY(); 
} catch (PDOException $e){die($e->getMessage());}
} is not working!

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::FETCH_ARRAY()

Comment: @user3706926 Looks like you are using PDO. The equivalent function is [fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)